# Is there any id that can be used for different idocs other than tid?

Tags: java, jco, idoc

Is there any id that can be used for different IDocs other than Transaction ID (tid)?

I am using `JCoServerTIDHandler` to get the tid.

Do we have any other such unique ID or other related field that helps the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

It is important to know for what purpose you need this ID. 
[TID](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_46c/helpdata/en/52/16ac10543311d1891c0000e8322f96/content.htm?frameset=/en/52/16abf6543311d1891c0000e8322f96/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/19/3cf334c20ccc52e10000009b38f83b/plain.htm&node_id=89) is used for checking consistency of communication with external system. Yes, it is globally unique, but in general transactional RFC (tRFC) it is used to prevent multiple execution in case of errors, not in case of successful calls. So it is generated not for every IDoc.
Another unique ID is `DOCNUM` (IDoc number). It is SAP internal identifier that every created IDoc has. It can be found in `EDIDS` table along with TID and can be selected from there by TID. 
Another way to get DOCNUM is launch FM `INBOUND_IDOCS_FOR_TID`.